# Substract passed object name from a function argument

Tags: r

I have a question about substr, but I don´t know if its what I need to use. I have simplified the example to the minimum, so I only need the result on this to duplicate it in a function and loop through it.

Imagine you have a date frame ("House"), but inside the function, you have to refer at it as input. As there will be many Data Frames going through it an it can´t be called "House" specifically.

So, Data Frame "House". Inside the function, get the name of input. But then, I want to compare the three first letters of the Data Frame name with "Hou". If it´s TRUE, it will return some value, if it´s false return another value.

I have tried but I can´t figure it out. I don´t know if someone would be able to help me or my question will fall in a black spot forever.

Any help would be usefull. I need the answeer to be `[1] TRUE`.

```
House <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Country" = c("Spain","France"), "Name" = c("John","Dora"))

input <- House

((substr("input", start=1, stop=3) == "Hou"))

[1] FALSE

Is there any way, to make this TRUE? I always get FALSE, as what it´s doing is compare "inp" with "Hou". 

If I take the quotes out,

House <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Country" = c("Spain","France"), "Name" = c("John","Dora"))

input <- House

(substr(input, start=1, stop=3) == "Hou"))

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: you should have House as string in "" and input without ""

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data frame as `input` and string to match as `word`.

```
foo <- function(input, word = "Hou") {
    name <- as.character(substitute(input))
    res <- substr(name, 1, 3) == word
    return(res)
}

House <- Duck <- data.frame()
foo(House)
[1] TRUE
foo(Duck)
[1] FALSE
```

Edit (respond to OP's comment):

```
foo <- function(input, word = "Hou") {
    name <- as.character(substitute(input))
    res <- substr(name, 1, 3) == word
    if (res) {
        nametitle <- input[1, 2] 
    } else {
        nametitle <- input[1, 3]
    }
    return(nametitle) 
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Imagine that before the function, we call the data frame
input <- house and then we writte the function

foo <- function(input, word = "Hou") {
    name <- as.character(substitute(input))
    res <- substr(name, 1, 3) == word
    return(res)
}

Then, what I would need its 
foo(input)
[1] TRUE

Comment: I don´t want to waste your time any more, but what I need its exactly that.

The only thing, if in tha example, "House" inside quotes, its just the word house. But what I have, is the dataframe house.

If you could take out the quoutes an call it input <- House and make it work, that would be exactly what I need

Comment: @JM_44 no problem,  but can you please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: I have many dataframes called House1, House2, House3... and also Street1, Street2, Street3... For each input, there is an inside function that creates a plot. I have a plot for each data frame. 

I gave to the plot title a generic name, let´s call it nametitle. And for each plot, if its a House data frame, i want to give the title of the 1st row and 2nd column. If its a Street data frame, I want the title to be 1st row and 3rd column.

So. i´ve created a function as follows,

if ((substr("input", start=1, stop=3) == "Hou")){
nametitle <- input[1,2]
} else {
nametitle <- input[1,3]
}

Comment: But with this function, I always get as nametitle, row 1st column 3 of the input, as I don´t get back "Hou" or "Str" to compare it to == "Hou", I get back "inp" and it neves == to "Hou"

If I take out the quote from "input", what I get it´s a vector with false, as it compares every item in the data frame with "Hou", and not the tittle.

Comment: @JM_44 Please see edited answer, it outputs `nametitle` now

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function? The standard trick is `deparse(substitute(.))`.

```
fun <- function(input){
    inpName <- deparse(substitute(input))
    substr(inpName, start=1, stop=3) == "Hou"
}

fun(House)
#[1] TRUE
```